# Representation of a real function as a sum of binary functions.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be a fixed finite set, and consider the family $F$ of all functions that go from $A$ to $\{0,1\}$. That is, $F=\{f: A \to \{0,1\}\}$.

Consider a subfamily $B$ of such functions, $B \subseteq F$ such that:

For every function $g:A \to [0,1]$, there exists $|B|$ non-negative real numbers $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_{|B|}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{|B|}\alpha_i \leq 1$ such that $g(x) = \sum_{f \in B} \alpha_f \cdot f(x)$ for all $ x \in A$.

What can be said about the minimum size of the B? For example, can we always find a set $B$ that has a cardinality less than $|A|$?

Comment: Another way to state it is, for fixed $N$, what is the least $M$ such that every element in an arbitrary collection $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N \in [0, 1]$ can be expressed as a sum of elements from $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_M$ (the $\alpha$-set depends on the $x$-set). In this sense, the $\alpha_i$ act like a "basis" for the $x_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let all the a's be 1.  For clarity let A = {1, 2,.. n}.
Thus g is a sequence of n binary divers.
There are n$^2$ such sequences.
Define f$_{g,x}$ to be 0 everywhere except at x where it's value is g(x).
As B is larger than A, define the f's to be 0 beyond A.
Those d's will have the desired summation propi8erty.
Thus a lower bound for |B| is n$^3$.

This lower bound can be refined by being picky about choosing the a's.
For each g, define a$_x$ = g(x) and a$_x$ = 0 for x's beyond A.
Except for the all 0 sequence define f$_{g,x}$ only when g(x) = 1.
There is one f for the 0 sequence.
There are n f's for the sequences with exactly one 1.
So on for the other sequences with exactly k 1's.
This adds up for a lower bound of n$^2$.

This problem would be simplified by summing on A instead of B.

Comment: What do you mean by "let all the a's be 1"?

Comment: Also, g is a function from A to the real numbers in [0,1]. So there are an infinite number of g's. Not $n^2$ as you mention.